# Receiving no errors but not seeing an output

Tags: arrays, c, compiler-errors

I'm currently learning C from an analog copy of The C Programming language. While it has been helpful in understanding the fundamental aspects of programming, I'm having trouble in understanding how my programs copied directly from the examples in the textbook are not producing an output in the terminal, nor are they explicitly requesting an input. I figured there's a giant hole in my comprehension of what's going on.

Currently I'm on section 1.6 on arrays. Here's the example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else 
            ++nother;

    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);

 }
```

In the text since it's C89, it didn't include the `int` before `main()`, which I added. It's not spitting out any errors, but it also isn't spitting out anything else after I compile it. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you *running* the program, or only *compiling* it? To build and run a C program you need to do it in multiple steps: 1) Edit the source code; 2) Build the source code into an executable program; 3) Run the program.

Comment: I'm also sort of wondering if you even know how to send an EOF with your keyboard.

Comment: @Blindy He doing it with a textbook. Sure thing the textbook has a mention of how to send `EOF`.

Comment: You need to type some keys, press `Enter` and then type the key combination `Ctrl-D` (Linux) or `Ctrl-Z` (Windows),  and possibly another `Enter`. Also, unless you run the program from a console, you might not see any output at all (it closes before you can).

Comment: Leevee, what was your input?  How did you cause the end-of-file signal?

Comment: Another thing you can do is to change the `EOF` to `'q'` and then that key (followed by `Enter`) will cause termination.

Comment: Try `echo 0123 | ./a.out`  , or. `echo -n 0123 | ./a.out`

Comment: As far as I know, I have compiled the program and after poking around various other stack posts, attempted to run it.  @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @Blindy and @yvm, the textbook explained EOF in the previous section discussing `getchar()` and `putchar()`. Admittedly, those processes and programs without any specifically indicated input proved difficult to understand so I moved onto arrays thinking I'd come back to it later. SO that's why I'm here now, haha

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It didn't specify an input to incorporate. I thought it was weird but I'm new at this and figured it would eventually make sense and spit out something.

Comment: @Leevee How are you compiling it? If you're using an IDE ( for example Code::Blocks ), after compiling you want to run the code. In your case the output will be a blank terminal. Try typing into the terminal and hitting enter. :)

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the code and it does work.

I want to make sure that you are running the compiled file.  After you compile a code file that ends in .c, there will be an executable file that you have to run to make the compiled program actually execute.

If you are running the compiled file, then I think the problem you are having is that the program keeps trying to get chars until it reads EOF (end of file).  The line "while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)" accomplishes 2 things.  First, it gets a character from standard input, storing it in the variable "c".  Second, it breaks out of the loop only when the variable "c" contains EOF.  The print statements below the while loop will never be reached if the program never reads EOF from standard input.  If your input is coming from the terminal (this is the default setting fore standard input), you will need to make the program read EOF manually by pressing Ctrl-D (if you are using Linux or Unix) or Ctrl-Z (if you are using Windows).

I noticed that you said that the program is not "explicitly asking for input."  This program doesn't have any print statements before the calls to "getchar()".  When this program runs, it won't give much of an indicator that it is expecting input because there is no code that prints text to the terminal asking for input.  Once you run the code, try just typing the input and pressing the "enter" key after each input.

Comment: Ah-ha! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain what it's doing. I followed your instructions and admittedly was a little miffed when my terminal closed completely after hitting Ctrl-D, but sure enough found the executable file and it worked! Thanks so much for you help.